# Pass arrays as parameters with jQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call in the following format:

```
$.get('/controller/method/',
  {
    parameter1: value1,
    parameter2: value2
  },
  function(data) {
    if (data) {
    }
  else {
  }
});
```

Is it possible to pass an array as a parameter?

```
parameter3: new Array(1, 2, 3)
parameter4: new Array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3)
```

Comment: Yes, I only have access to the last parameter of the array in the PHP script, referencing it as, for example, $_GET['parameter3']

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will probably need to name your variable as "parameter3[]" for PHP's sake:

```
$.get('/controller/method/',
  {
    "parameter1": "value1",
    "parameter2": "value2",
    "parameter3[]": ["a","b","c"]
  },
  function(data) {
    if (data) {
    }
  else {
  }
});
```

$_GET["parameter3"] will appear in PHP as

```
Array
(
    [0] => "a"
    [1] => "b"
    [2] => "c"
)
```

Comment: Nice! Works very well. Now I don't have to deal with worrying about whether my parameter values contain separator values (eg. commas). A little weird to have to quote the variable name.

Comment: Well, short of writing your own query string deserializer this is the standard -and only- way to deal with multi-valued form inputs, like checkboxes and selects. PHPland is indeed a weird place to live in.

Comment: I've even used this method for regular array passing

Answer (score 1):

I've been down this road before.  Join your array with a comma (or whatever character will work best for your scenario) and send it as a single parameter...

```
var arr = [5, "x", 25];
var parms = {
  parameter1: "value1",
  parameter2: arr.join(",");
}
```

And on the server-side, your "parameter2" post variable will look like `5,x,25`

This is an easy solution for both sides of the wire.

Comment: Josh Stodola solution using the join() method worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send any JSON object through a post command... even to an MVC controller.  The difficult part is receiving the data... which you may need to deserialize manually at the server (either in the controller or with a JSON filter.

Comment: Ahhh! You just added now that you are doing this in PHP, which my link won't help you with.  For PHP, you need to intercept the request message which will be you JSON object and then deserialize it into an object.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, I think you're mixing JavaScript and PHP syntax. This is probably what you meant to do to demonstrate passing arrays:

```
    $.get('foo.htm',
      {
        parameter1: 'value1',
        parameter2: 'value2',
        parameter3: [1, 2, 3],
        parameter4: {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
      },
      function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
```

Oddly enough JQuery doesn't like the nested object. It creates a query string like this:

```
 foo.htm?parameter1=value1
   &parameter2=value2
   &parameter3=1
   &parameter3=2
   &parameter3=3
   &parameter4=%5Bobject+Object%5D
```

For PHP passing back and forth complex objects, I recommend serializing your JavaScript object using a [JSON stringify](http://www.JSON.org/js.html) method and de-serializing it on the backend with [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode).

Also, it appears you're using some MVC framework. If it's CodeIgniter and you're having trouble with GETs, consider using this postJSON helper method:

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
    $.post(url, data, callback, "json");
};
```