# How to pass an array as a querystring in a GET request by using JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, serialization, get

In my javascript application I am trying to pass an array of strings, among other parameters, in a GET request to an ASP.NET Web API REST service by using jQuery Ajax. 
An example URL is as follows:

```
http://my.services.com/products?userId=1abc&id=1&id=2&id=3
```

The signature of the Web API method:

```
[HttpGet("products")]
public IActionResult GetProducts(string userId, int[] id)
```

If I try the request with Postman the binding of the parameters works correctly. In the Javascript app I tried several solutions with no luck. The code is as follows:

```
let data = {
  'userId': '1abc'
  'id': [1,2,3]
}

$.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: 'http://my.services.com/products',
   data: data,
   crossDomain: true, //CORS
   cache: false,
}
```

In this case the URL becomes:

```
http://my.services.com/products?userId=1abc&id%5B%5D=1&id%5B%5D=2&id%5B%5D=3
```

since in the parsed result instead of using `id` as key, it uses `id[]`, therefore codifies the characters `[]` as `%5B` and `%5D`.

No luck even if I use this code:

```
let data = {
  'userId': '1abc'
  'id': JSON.stringify([1,2,3])
}
```

or (as seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522257/pass-arrays-as-parameters-with-jquery-ajax))

```
let data = {
  'userId': '1abc'
  'id[]': [1,2,3]
}
```

Keep in mind that for the other calls the code JQuery AJAX code above works without any issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem with the request is because the default ASP.Net model binder expects arrays to be sent through the querystring as separate key/value pairs, as your first example URL shows.

To achieve this you simply need to set `traditional: true` in your jQuery `$.ajax()` request:

```
let data = {
  userId: '1abc'
  id: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
}

$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'http://my.services.com/products',
  data: data,
  traditional: true
});
```

Also, as a side note, be wary of using absolute URLs when making AJAX requests, you can easily encounter CORS issues if the code isn't maintained routinely. I'd suggest using relative paths where possible.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works, I didn't know about this traditional parameter. I edited my question since the syntax issue was a typo I made during the copy/pasting the code.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I removed the note about the syntax :)

Comment: Note for all the people use other backends (like Drupal, PHP): use traditional: false (default).

Comment: For those wondering what traditional is for like me: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/